# Database deployment inadvertently dropping SQL Broker objects in database if the user is not a sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a Database Project. I am trying to deploy that project against a database. The Database deployment is inadvertently dropping SQL Broker objects in database not in source (database project) if the user is not a sysadmin

Using Visual Studio and using Dacpac deployment gave same results. In my publish profile, Drop is unchecked, so it should not try to drop objects in target that are not in source. That is working fine if the user account is a sysadmin. But if it is not, it is dropping all sql broker objects in the database that are not in source

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason for the database deployment behaving differently for sysadmin vs non-sysadmin. I ran a sql trace while I did "Generate Script" from Visual Studio database publish.

During the non-sa publish, the trace captured an exception in tempdb database that said "this "Cannot alter the schema 'dbo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.".

I had a script with "CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION" as part of my database project which was failing due to insufficient privilege.

Because of this exception, the deployment process was deciding to generate all those "Drop" statements in the publish script. As soon as I granted the user account dbo access to tempdb and re-generated publish scripts, the drop statements went away from the publish scripts.